# Using Multiple GIDs in Google Sheet direct download

Tags: google-sheets, automation

I am trying to use the direct download link to download a PDF with from google sheets.

Each sheet reflects one GID, which I am able to pull easily.

For the download, I want to combine multiple GIDs in the link to ensure that given sheets tabs are downloaded (but not all respective sheet tabs).

For this, I tried the following two options.

Option 1 using multiple GID values by listing it multiple times only prints the first one, i.e.
`gid=1149564405&gid=1786412896` only prints `gid=1149564405`

Option 2 using a comma and only one gids to an access error code:
i.e. using `gid=1149564405,1786412896` leads to an access error message:
"Data can not be accessed".

What other options do I have? What am I missing?

My whole download link would look something like this:
[https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/[SpreadSheet-ID]/export?exportFormat=pdf&top_margin=0&bottom_margin=0&left_margin=0&right_margin=0&scale=2&fitw=true&horizontal_alignment=CENTER&vertical_alignment=TOP&gid=1149564405&gid=1786412896](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/%5BSpreadSheet-ID%5D/export?exportFormat=pdf&top_margin=0&bottom_margin=0&left_margin=0&right_margin=0&scale=2&fitw=true&horizontal_alignment=CENTER&vertical_alignment=TOP&gid=1149564405&gid=1786412896)

Help would be greatly appreciated. Downloading each sheet seperate is not really applicable.

**Thanks!**

Answer (score 1):

Downloading multiple sheets with the method above will not work, this only works for one sheet at a time or all sheets. Instead you can try a workaround with Apps Script. To give you an idea, you can try with the following script.

```js
function downloadPDF(){
  var spreadsheetId = "spreadsheet_Id";
  var source = SpreadsheetApp.openById(spreadsheetId);
  var sheets = ["SheetB", "SheetC"] //Enter the name of the sheets that you want to download
  var temp = SpreadsheetApp.create("TempFile") //Creating a new sheet to copy the sheets you specified above

  //Going through all the sheets you specified above in the 'sheets' variable and copying them to the new file
  sheets.forEach(el => {
    var sheet = source.getSheetByName(el);
    sheet.copyTo(temp);
  })
  
  //Deleting the sheet that was first created when creating the SpreadSheet
  var sheet1 = temp.getSheetByName("Sheet1")
  temp.deleteSheet(sheet1)

  var downloadURL = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/"+temp.getId()+"/export?exportFormat=pdf&top_margin=0&bottom_margin=0&left_margin=0&right_margin=0&scale=2&fitw=true&horizontal_alignment=CENTER&vertical_alignment=TOP";
  Logger.log(downloadURL)
}
```

The script above will return a URL to download the file with the specific sheets that you define in the `sheets` variable.

Comment: Hi, I tried your script, but received the following error message: "Exception: Unexpected error while getting the method or property openById on object SpreadsheetApp." .. Inside the script, I only changed the sheets variable.. 

Where is the error coming from in your opinion?  

Anyway, I somewhat understand your idea, but I am struggling with the concept of how these new sheets are formated to be printed properly? How would you ensure, that the page breaks are at the correct marks?

Comment: In the script, replace `spreadsheet_Id` with a valid Spreadsheet ID. For example, the spreadsheet ID in the URL https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/abc1234567/edit#gid=0 is "abc1234567".

Comment: Okay, that what not my brightest moment. Well anyway, first of. Thanks again!

Anyway, the methods makes sense to me. issues that I currently have using this method is:
1.) All connections between spreadsheets are lost (i.e. the new PDF shows a lot of #REF errors)       2.) I found the downloadURL in the logger. How do I manage to activate / run it directly, instead of sending it to the logger only? 

Thanks a lot!